# Is there a way to capture popovers in macOS?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I want to capture popovers in macOS, to use them in my blog. 
But I couldn't find a good way to do it: whenever I try to capture them as windows (CMD+Shift+4, then spacebar), the area will include the windows they attach to.
Is there a better way to capture the popovers (clean, but including their shadows)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by accident: after the camera icon appears, press and hold ⌘ key, then click the popover or sheet.